# how to use while to search for many results in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have two tables and each contains one column: Column A(in table positive) is a list of words and column B(in table body) is a list of long paragraphs.

```
column A         
abound  
abounds  
abundance  
abundant  
accessable  
accessible  
acclaim  
.......

column B
 Works great.....   
 I registered for ....
 We started with the
 This is an excellent idea having the
```

I am about to search the occurrence of each word from column A in the paragraphs from column B. I got this code from my friend, she use SQL server.

My question is I can not run the code because I am not a experienced MySQL player and I don't know how to translate the code from SQL server to MySQL, I tried to google that and I failed. I would appreciate if someone can point out the places that need to be edited.
My Code is

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE counting ()
BEGIN

DECLARE id int ;
DECLARE max int;
DECLARE count int;
DECLARE word varchar(20);
DECLARE string varchar(500);
DECLARE fake_str varchar(100);
set id = 1
select max(count) from ( SELECT count(word) as count from positive
SELECT max = select count(word) from positive
while id <= max
select word = word from positive where id = id
set fake_str = quotename('%'+ @word +'%','''')
set string = declare count int,id int set count = (select count(*) from bodyTL7P where comments like ' + fake_str + ') print count 
               update positive set times = count' + ' where id = '+ cast(id as varchar)

exec (string)
set id = id + 1

END
select * from positive
//
DELIMITER ;
```

I add the test sample from her computer to make things more clear.

[Test sample from SQL server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DtmK.png)

Comment: This site is for programming questions. it is not a code translation service.

Comment: Some suggestions: avoid using names of MySQL functions as variable names or identifiers. Use a naming convention for variables that disambiguate them from column references. There are syntax errors in your first SELECT query. At a minimum, it's missing a closing paren and a alias for the inline view. And that query is going to return a resultset, when it looks like you want to assign it to a variable. The assignment operator in a SELECT statement is the pascal style **`:=`**, the `=` operator is a comparison. The individual statements must be terminated with a `;` delimiter. Et al.

Comment: "I don't know how to translate" is *not* a good question. It's not even a very interesting question. It barely qualifies as a question at all.   http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Here's a recommendation... If you want to learn to write a MySQL stored program... start with a *simple* stored program, like a procedure that just declares a variable and assigns a value to it. Get that created and get that running. Once that is working, add a SELECT statement. And get that working. Then, when you run into a problem, you'll have a better idea where the problem is. I recommend you do that, vs trying to untangle a bloatload of code that has a lot of different problems.

Comment: SQL Server has a free version for personal use; using it may be your path of least resistance.

Comment: Sorry guys, I know this question is inappropriate, and I asked it in a very bad way. Turned out I was in a wrong direction thus I chose this wrong method. I am now all set by using the length replace function. I really appreciate your time and insights here!!!